# Webhooks for email hard-bounce in Campaign Monitor API

Tags: php, api, email, campaign-monitor

I am working on sending emails through campaign monitor API. I want to know if the CM provides the webhooks for email hard-bounce/spam etc. I check the documentation but couldn't found any info regarding this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valid events for our webhooks are Subscribe, Deactivate, and Update: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/api/lists/#creating_a_webhook. You might also want to look into these API calls:

Campaign Bounces: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/api/campaigns/#campaign_bounces

Campaign spam complaints: (sorry, I don't have enough reputation points to post 3 links, but you'll see it on the same page as the API call for bounces)

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Balthazar for helping me.